# missing parenthesis after argument in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write live search program but it is not working. Here is the script I am using

```
function Selectcountry(value)
{
    $.post("getRecord.php",{partialstate: value},function(data)
        $("#RecordResult").html(data);
    });
}
```

This is the error that it returns:

> missing ) after argument list

Comment: You're not closing the $.post properly. }); should be );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing braces in the success function of post request

```
       function Selectcountry(value) { 
    $.post("getRecord.php",{partialstate:value},function(data){
         $("#RecordResult").html(data); 
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `{` after the start of the function inside `$.post`.

```
function Selectcountry(value)
{
    $.post("getRecord.php", {partialstate:value}, function(data)
    {
        $("#RecordResult").html(data);
    });
}
```

These mistakes are easier to spot if you organize your syntax consistently.